# How do I reference System.Windows 5.0.5 assembly (Silverlight) from .NET 4.5 library project?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, .net-assembly

I have a project written for Silverlight 5, which references Silverlight's `System.Windows` assembly in version 5.0.5.

Now I want to create a unit test project for it using a usual .NET 4.5 library project. When I try to add a reference to the `System.Windows` assembly 5.0.5 from Silverlight (using the `browse` dialog), Visual Studio adds the version from .NET 4.5.

Hence the version number does not match.

- Why does Visual Studio behave this way?
- How do I fix this?

Comment: Surely it is because you created a .NET 4.5 library project.  Arbitrarily google "silverlight unit testing" to find hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* reference Silverlight assemblies from a .Net project, but once you have managed to add one, you will likely have problems with dependencies on other libraries.

It will be easier on you if you to try a different approach...

I would suggest using the [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) to deal with testing your Silverlight code.

If that doesn't fit your need, perhaps [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) will.